# Get table to fill remaining width

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my table to fill the remaining space within a floated element. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example Table]

And this is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
    width: 125px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
.right {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
table {
    background: green;
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
```

I tried `width: 100%` but that doesn't take into account the left-floated element and the table gets hidden outside the container. I also tried `display: block` but that causes the `<td>` to no longer function as they would if they were inside a table.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gXLC/)

Comment: you try display: table; ?

Comment: Depending on compatibility you can use `calc()` [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/8gXLC/3/) - More info on `calc()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are `float`ing your `.left` div with the fixed `width` you can use a combination of the `overflow:auto` and `width:auto` (default value) to expand your `.right` div. Also uncomment `width:100%` to make table take the full width of the `.right` div:

```
.right {
  overflow:auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gXLC/4/)